# Getting trace on odoo server log

Tags: odoo

While starting the server I am getting the server trace.

```
ERROR odoo openerp.addons.base.ir.ir_cron: Call of self.pool.get('osv_memory.autovacuum').power_on(cr, uid, *()) failed in Job 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_cron.py", line 138, in _callback
    getattr(model, method_name)(cr, uid, *args)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/osv_memory_autovacuum.py", line 31, in power_on
    model._transient_vacuum(cr, uid, force=True)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4985, in _transient_vacuum
    self._transient_clean_rows_older_than(cr, self._transient_max_hours * 60 * 60)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/openerp/models.py", line 4949, in _transient_clean_rows_older_than
    self.unlink(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, ids)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/software/ws/odoo/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 339, in unlink
    raise orm.except_orm(_('Error'), _('You try to remove a module that is installed or will be installed'))
except_orm: (u'Error', u'You try to remove a module that is installed or will be installed')
```

It may be because cron is failed. can anyone tell me how to overcome on this trace?

Comment: Check this [Link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+bug/359355), this might help you.  :)

Comment: @Mischievous Thanks for the comment, I have checked but there is no module which is in 'to be installed' state

Comment: @OpenWorks Have You try to check the server with update all options

Comment: @DaSaDiYaChaiTAnYa what happens with update all option?

Comment: update all options mens that refresh your database table

Comment: @DaSaDiYaChaiTAnYa is it Feasible  in live database ?

Comment: if you want to in local then you can other u can also do on live as well